# Different keyboard shortcut for Windows 8 start screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, start-menu, start-screen

By default, the Windows key will go to the start screen on Windows 8. But I'm using this program called Pokki that adds a classic Windows-like (pre-Win 8) start menu to Windows 8. And I've enabled the option to invoke Pokki when the Windows key is pressed. The problem now is that I have no way to get to the Windows start screen using a keyboard shortcut. I know in another start menu replacement app (Classic Shell, I believe), there is the option to have Ctrl+Windows bring up the Windows 8 start screen.

My question is: Is there a way to assign Ctrl+Windows as the keystroke that will bring up the Windows 8 start screen? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just change the Pokki settings? I think Autohotkey can change the Windows shortcuts, but I am not sure it will work with the winkey ones.

Comment: Well the core issue is that I would like a keyboard shortcut for both Pokki and Windows 8 start screen. Currently, it doesn't look like Pokki provides any keyboard shortcuts for its menu other than replacing the Windows key. If you're aware of one, please let me know.

Comment: Windows 8.1 or Windows 8.0?

Comment: Windows 8.1. Sorry I forgot to specify.

Comment: Pokki is a start screen replacement so it actually replaces the start menu and start screen into a non-standard menu StartIsBack restore the start menu and has a Ctrl+winkey to display the start screen

Comment: StartIsBack is what I meant when I said classic shell. I actually figured it out using the following method: classic shell installs with it a utility called StartScreen.exe that launches the Win 8 start screen. I used AutoHotkey to wire that up to ctrl+win and left Pokki to be launched on Win key press. The only thing was that I have a yoga 2 pro and that had a Win key on the touchscreen which I thought would also be routed to Pokki but turns out that's only the case when it's in laptop mode. When you turn it to tablet mode pokki must be smart enough to disable itself.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> `+` <kbd>Esc</kbd> is what you are looking for. It's an alternative key to launch start menu.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to create a desktop shortcut and assign a keyboard shortcut to it. Unfortunately, you can only use Crtl+Alt+ or F keys.

- Download [this zip](http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/39495d1394657625-start-screen-shortcut-create-windows-8-start_flag_shortcut.zip) and extract it anywhere.
- Create a desktop shortcut of the exe.
- Right click on the shortcut, select properties and change the shortcut in the Shortcut tab.

Source: [Eightforums](http://eightforums.com/)